# How to get starred files using the Google Drive Api and a service account?

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I am developing an app locally which will eventually run on Google App Engine in Go.

I'm using a service account key as suggested in the cloud docs:

> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication
>
> Accessing private data on behalf of a service account outside Google
> Cloud environments
>
> Recommendation: Service account key

This is the intended workflow:

1. The admin creates a Drive folder which is shared with select users and the service account.
2. The users can create files in that shared folder.
3. The admin can star a selection of those files and invoke the app.
4. The app queries for starred files in that shared folder and processes those files.

Now if the admin uses the Files: list "Try this API" at:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

with the this query string:

```
parents in 're89w...r9d9' and starred
```

then the starred files show up.

However when my app uses the same string:

```
q := "parents in '" + folderID + "' and starred "
fl, err = srvDrive.Files.List().PageSize(100).Q(q).Fields("nextPageToken, files(name)").Do()
```

then fl is an empty list; there are no starred files.

I suspect it has something to do with using a service account and there may be a way to fix this by impersonating something in some way, but the docs get deep and I'm not sure it will even help if I figure it out.

How does my app query for starred files in the admin's drive?

Comment: I had the same situation. I think that this is a bug or the current specification for the service account. Because for example, when `files(name,starred)` is used for `fields`, even when the files with the star are existing in the folder, the field of `starred` is always `false` for all files. I think that this is the reason of your issue. So in the current stage, unfortunately, the starred file list cannot be directly retrieved using the service account. For example, how about reporting it to Google issue tracker as the future request?

Comment: @Tanaike. Thanks, I have lodged an issue, please feel free to star it:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179060625

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now by including more information I proposed the workarounds for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? By the way, I confirmed your issue tracker. So I starred to it. As the additional information to your issue tracker, how about adding the following information? When the service account is used and `files(name,starred)` is used for `fields`, even when the files with the star are existing in the folder, the field of `starred` is always `false` for all files. This might be the reason of the issue.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue on Google's side. Files starred by the service account can be returned via `Files: list`. At least that's the behaviour I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I understood that your current situation is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list of the files which have the star from the specific folder.
- The folder is shared between your account and the service account, and you can see the starred files in your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using googlapis for golang.

I had the same situation. I thought that this is a bug or the current specification for the service account.

Because for example, when `files(name,starred)` is used for `fields`, even when the files with the star are existing in the folder, the field of `starred` is always `false` for all files. I think that this is the reason of the issue.

So in the current stage, I thought that unfortunately, the starred file list cannot be directly retrieved using the service account. When you want to retrieve the starred file list, how about the following workarounds?

#### Workaround 1:

In this workaround, the file list in the specific folder can be retrieved with the access token retrieved from OAuth2 instead of the service account. In this case, the starred file list can be retrieved.

#### Workaround 2:

In this workaround, the file list is retrieved using the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script, and when the script of golang requests to the Web Apps, the file list is returned. In this case, the access token retrieved from the service account can be used. Also, this can be used without using the access token. In this workaround, the Web Apps is used as an API. By this, although at the workaround 1, it is required to use OAuth2 process in the script of golang, this workaround can avoid it, and the service account can be used.

#### note:

- For example, how about reporting it to Google issue tracker as the future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)
- By the way, in your script, `q := "parents in '" + folderID + "' and starred "` is used as the search query. When I saw [the official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files), it seems `'1234567' in parents`. But, when I test `parents in '1234567'`, I confirmed that this can be used. I thought that this specification might be changed.
- And also, I thought that in this case, to include `trashed = false` in `fields` might be suitable.

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thank you very much for that detail answer. Have you considered @Iamblichus solution below for Go specifically? From a lot of issue reading I suspect a service account impersonating an admin can't be done with Go?

Comment: This is most certainly not an issue, since the service account can definitely find files starred by it. It's just that, in this case, the files were not starred by the service account but by a regular user.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for your comment. Now I noticed that you had posted your answer. I apologize for this. Although when I posted this answer, I was not sure whether this situation is a bug or the current specification, from your comment and answer, I could know that it's the specification. Thank you for your always support.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

A file is not starred in itself. A file is starred **for a specific user**, as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations):

> **starred**: Whether the user has starred the file.

This means a certain account (#1) can have starred a certain file while another one (#2) has not. Because of this, when querying `starred` files with #1, the file will be returned, and when doing it with #2, it will not. I think this is what's happening here: your regular (admin) account has starred certain files, while your service account (which is a completely different account) has not.

**Because of this, I don't think this is an issue on Google's side: service accounts can be used to return files they have starred. I checked that's the case by (1) starring a file with a service account and (2) query starred files via `q="starred"`. The starred file was returned**.

#### Solution:

If you want to use the service account to retrieve the files starred by a regular user, you should grant the service account domain-wide authority and use that to impersonate the user.

The workaround #2 [provided by Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66002356) could also be a good option if you want to avoid domain-wide delegation.

#### Update:

You are using Go, and unfortunately the corresponding API library doesn't yet include the functionality for impersonating domain users with a service account. Here is the related feature request from the library repo: [support impersonating admin users for gSuite APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/652) (please note that [this other FR](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/378), already implemented, refers to a different functionality).

Meanwhile, I can try going through the impersonation process without using the library. See [Preparing to make an authorized API call: HTTP/REST](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest) for an overall guide.

#### Reference:

- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

Comment: The doc section you reference ends with, "When you prepare to make authorized API calls, you specify the user to impersonate."
The trouble is, I can't see any way to do this with the Go Drive API V3 client?

Comment: @DavidSmith I think this functionality is still not available to the Go library. Here is the related feature request: [support impersonating admin users for gSuite APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/652) (please note that [this other FR](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/378), already implemented, refers to a different functionality - impersonating another service account).

Comment: @DavidSmith Meanwhile, I think you should make do without the library. See [Preparing to make an authorized API call: HTTP/REST](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest) for an overall guide.

Comment: @DavidSmith I updated my answer to add this information.